# How can I access flash variable by using JSP

Tags: java, actionscript-3, jsp, flash

I have created a simple login form in Adobe flash CS6 with 2 fields, username and password.
I want to send these data to a JSP page for the rest processes such as authentication.
The following image visualize the problem
[image]

The actions script I use is this

```
stop();
btnLogin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitted);

function submitted(event:MouseEvent):void
{
try{
trace("mouse clicked in button");
trace(txtUsername.text);
trace(txtPassword.text);
var myrequest:URLRequest = new  URLRequest("http://localhost:9093/JAVA&FLASH/index.jsp");
myrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.username = txtUsername.text;
variables.password = txtPassword.text;
myrequest.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad);
loader.load(myrequest);
}catch(e:Error){
    r.text=e.message;
}
}

function dataOnLoad(evt:Event):void
{
//This is the reverse mode. I mean that if I want to
//fetch JSP variable I should handle it here
}
```

and this is the JSP file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Using GET and POST Method to Read Form Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<object width="100" height="100" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://localhost:9093/JAVA&FLASH/LoginDB.swf"
        id="applicationID" >
    <param name="movie" value="http://localhost:9093/JAVA&FLASH/LoginDB.swf">
    <embed src="http://localhost:9093/JAVA&FLASH/LoginDB.swf" width="100"   height="100">

<h1>Using GET Method to Read Form Data</h1>
<ul>
    <li><p><b>First Name:</b>
        <%= request.getParameter("username")%>
    </p></li>
    <li><p><b>Last  Name:</b>
        <%= request.getParameter("password")%>
    </p></li>
</ul>
    </embed>
</object>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

the question is that JSP does not get any value. what should I do that I solve this problem

Comment: this is actionscript issue, the form is posted or not? this is the problem. Actionscript has an interface with javascript as well if nothing else helps and you can post the data from js if needed

Comment: I've develop a project that should interact with user and collect his data. I want to know how to solve this problem, then I adopt the rest project with this solution.